# Is this true $(A – B)\cap(C–B)=A–(B\cup C)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The Problem in my textbook was : For all sets $A,B$ and $C$ show that $(A–B)\cap(C–B)=A–(B\cup C)$
I tried the problem for about half an hour. Then I finally tried drawing a Venn diagram and I found out that the L.H.S was not equal to the R.H.S. I even tried using an example

---

Consider the sets $A=\{1,2,3,4\},B=\{3,4,5,6\},C=\{4,8,9,1\}$

(I've taken the sets randomly as there was no constraints or conditions specified in the problem.)

On the L.H.S you will get: $\{1,2\}\cap\{8,9,1\}=\{1\}$

And on the R.H.S you will get : $\{1,2,3,4\}-\{3,4,5,6,8,9,1\}=\{2\}$

Therefore, as you can see L.H.S is clearly not equal to R.H.S. Can someone verify this and if the problem is indeed incorrect, can someone modify it?

Comment: Isn't the LHS the part shared by $A$ and $C$ that isn't in $B$? so try $(A\cup C)-B$? The RHS should be the part in A that isn't in B or C so maybe try $(A-B)\cap (A-C)$?

Answer (score 1):

The problem as stated is incorrect, and the example provided proves that the statement is false.  However: the problem might have been a "prove or disprove"; in this case, the provided example gives a correct disproof.

---

A correct problem, similar to the one given, is to prove that $$(A\setminus B)\cap (A\setminus C) = A\setminus (B\cup C)$$

Comment: No, the problem strictly asked to prove it

Comment: Have you checked the errata for the book?